# Boolean result C programming

Tags: boolean

I need a function that returns 0 or 1, one value per input.
Input should come from keyboard, 1 per line.
Expected input is whitespace, 1 and 0.
1 - enter: should result in 1
0 - enter: should result in 0
space - enter: should result in 0
enter: should result in 0
tab - enter: should result in 0

What I've got now works fine for everything except enter alone, I'm using getchar() and a bunch of if statements, but I can't seem to get it to work.
getchar() seems to be difficult to manipulate to only give the input - or lack there of -
and not the newline char.

Grateful for any insight you might have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please be more specific.
you could do it like this one

```
#include <stdio.h>
// only if you dont want to wait for enter each get
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ()
{
   char c = 0;

   // only if you dont want to wait for enter each get
   struct termios newtty;
   tcgetattr (0, &newtty);
   newtty.c_lflag &= (~ICANON);
   tcsetattr (0, TCSANOW, &newtty);



   puts ("start\n");
   do {
      if(c == 0)
         c=getchar();
      switch(c)
      {
         case '1':
            c=getchar();
            if(c == '\n')
               putchar ('1');
            else
               continue;
            c = 0;
            break;
         case '0':
         case '\t':
            c=getchar();
            if(c == '\n')
               putchar ('0');
            else
               continue;
            c = 0;
            break;
         case '\n':
            putchar ('0');
            c = 0;
            break;
         default:
            c = 0;
            continue;
     }
  } while (1);
  return 0;
}
```